# Display XML file data in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to display xml file data in php but because of while loop it repeats data  more then required execution

The code...

```
// display data in table

        echo "<table  border='3' width='900' height='5' cellpadding='6' class='CSSTableGenerator'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td> '. $lang ['IMAGE']  ; '   </td>';   
        echo'<td>ID</td>'; 
        echo '<td> '. $lang ['PRODUCT_NAME']  ; '   </td>';  
        echo '<td> '. $lang ['PRODUCT_CATAGORY']  ; '   </td>';  
        echo '<td> '. $lang ['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION']  ; '   </td>'; 
        echo '<td> '. $lang ['PRODUCT_PRICE']  ; '   </td>'; 
         "</tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

             $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
             if(! $xml = simplexml_load_file('french_products.xml'));

             foreach($xml->children() as $Products){


                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";



                echo '<td><b>' . $row['id'] . '</b></td>';

                echo '<td><b>' .  $Products->product_name. '</b></td>';
                echo '<td><b>' . $row['product_category'] . '</b></td>';
                 echo '<td><b>' . $row['product_description'] . '</b></td>';
                  echo '<td><b>' . $row['product_price'] . '</b></td>';





    }
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
if(! $xml = simplexml_load_file('french_products.xml'));
```

Write this code before while loop. Hope this can help you.

Comment: still the same problem